# Can't install tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow

Request help as can't install
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iiy0.jpg)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute

```
result = await result
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 328, in __wakeup

```
future.result()
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run

```
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 74, in post

```
model = yield maybe_future(
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run

```
value = future.result()
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run

```
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 98, in create_session

```
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run

```
value = future.result()
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run

```
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel_for_session

```
kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run

```
value = future.result()
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 201, in result

```
raise self._exception
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 256, in __step

```
result = coro.send(None)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel

```
kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel

```
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 341, in start_kernel

```
self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 249, in _launch_kernel

```
return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 132, in launch_kernel

```
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in **init**

```
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child

```
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
```

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Request help as can't install
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iiy0.jpg)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute

```
result = await result
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 328, in __wakeup

```
future.result()
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run

```
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 74, in post

```
model = yield maybe_future(
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run

```
value = future.result()
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run

```
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 98, in create_session

```
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run

```
value = future.result()
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run

```
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel_for_session

```
kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run

```
value = future.result()
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 201, in result

```
raise self._exception
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 256, in __step

```
result = coro.send(None)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel

```
kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel

```
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 341, in start_kernel

```
self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 249, in _launch_kernel

```
return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 132, in launch_kernel

```
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in **init**

```
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
```

File "D:\Software_Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child

```
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
```

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system canno

Comment: Hi @vishant chopra, Could you please refer to the [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) official link to install tensorflow by following all the step by step instructions mentioned as per your system OS? Let us know if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As the commented solution worked, hence adding this in the answer section for the community benefit.)

It seems there is tensorflow installation issue in your system.

> Please refer to the [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) official link to install
> tensorflow by following all the step by step instructions mentioned as
> per your system OS.